# Making a vector template file to output artboards based on given parameters

Tags: adobe-illustrator, template-design

*We use **Adobe Illustrator** but we are willing to try any other Adobe software that may aid on this issue, .*

**Problem**: We have to make various graphical pieces for conferences, they always have the same layout and message (around 25 different artboards) but with different logos and color palette. This is rather simple but generates an enourmous amount of work.

**Our wish**: To make a template file where we can just set the palette and the logo and it updates all artboards accordingly. So far we did a proto version of it with the logo as a symbol and recolor artwork but there must be some better technique out there.

The following image is an oversimplified example of what we want.
[image: virtual example]

Answer (score 1):

- Set solid colors as **Global Colors** using the `Swatch Options` in the **Swatch Panel**. Create all gradients/meshes using these solid *global* colors and tints of these global colors.

[image]

When you edit a Global Color, by double-clicking the swatch in the **Swatch Panel**, *all uses* of that color will *also* be edited. So, it is only one edit to change colors applied to multiple objects.

[image]

---

- Use **Symbols** for logos.

If the logos are symbols, you can merely select them all and use the **Replace** option in the **Control Panel** across the top of the screen to replace all the logos in one step....

[image]

To create a Symbol, merely drag the artwork to the **Symbols Panel** (Window > Symbols)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry bout the "vectorial".

Comment: As I stated we are already using symbols for the logos, on the other hand the swatches work better than the recolor. Is there a way to keep those symbols and swatches in a linked file?

Comment: You can set up library files by saving swatches/symbols. And with CC, there is always the Libraries panel which stores library items in your Creative Cloud account online - so they are available to that CC account all the time. And, of course, you could edit start files to add items.